# Бессоюзные предложения

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "не могу, не должен, не стану(:) всё рухнет" нужно ли двоеточие и является ли второе предложение пояснением первого? По-моему, "потому что" влезает между частями (Не могу, потому что всё рухнет) и тире не может стоять, т. к. "всё" не является обобщающим словом.

Comment: *По моему "потому что" влезает между частями* - Я не вижу в вашей фразе слов  "потому что". А "по-моему" пишется через дефис.

Comment: Исправил. "Не могу (потому что) всё рухнет" разве не подходит? Это же причина, а если причина, то ставим двоеточие

Comment: *Не причина, а пояснение того, о чем говорится в первой части.

Comment: *"Не могу (потому что) всё рухнет" разве не подходит?* -  Не могу ответить, для чего "не подходит"? Постарайтесь внятно оформлять вопросы, а то у вас то "влезает", то "не подходит".

Comment: Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении, распадающемся на две части, ставится если вторая часть указывает основание, причину того, о чем говорится в первой части (между обеими частями можно вставить союз потому что, так как, поскольку), например: Он покраснел: ему было стыдно убить человека безоружного... (Лермонтов)

Comment: Да ладно, теперь-то. Вам надо было это в вопросе внятно написать, как и о чем вы думали, а не мне рассказывать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Если нет контекста, в предложении возможны два знака - двоеточие и тире.

Не могу , не должен, не стану: (потому что) всё рухнет" (вторая часть указывает на причину).

Не могу , не должен, не стану - (так что) всё рухнет" (следствие).

Comment: Не так вё однозначно и просто, как хотелось бы. Из Правил Лопатина: В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, ПРИЧИНЫ, обоснования, изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике). Татьяна Андреевна вздрагивала от сырости — (потому что) после теплой каюты на палубе было свежо.

Comment: Допустимо так допустимо. Я не спорю. Случай здесь прозрачный, затруднений никаких. И тире, и двоеточие возможны и вполне объяснимы. Всё отлично!

Comment: Мне как раз не показалось, что прозрачный, так как здесь два противоположных смысла заключены в одинаковой форме. (1)  (если) не сделаю, не выполню,  то все рухнет (вывод: надо обязательно сделать). (2) не сделаю, не выполню (= не буду делать), так как все тогда рухнет (вывод: этого нельзя делать).

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем понимаю смысл вопроса, но если говорить о выборе знака, то я за тире. Тому есть несколько причин.

Тире вообще такой знак, что его, единственный из всех, почти всегда можно поставить просто по "личным мотивам" для передачи авторской интонации, периода, противопоставления и бог знает чего еще. Двоеточие же ставится только тогда, когда автор наверняка знает, зачем оно тут.

Начнем с того, что первая часть в силу своей определенно-личной структуры позволяет трактовать себя состоящей либо как из трех однородных главных членов, либо как из "однородных" полноценных неопределенно-личных предложений (обычно выбирается первый вариант, но это не императив).

В результате нашу фразу с точки зрения семантики или акцентуации можно корректно трактовать несколькими способами.

1. Первая часть главная (вывод) - вторая подчиненная (причина или условие): *"Не могу: все рухнет" (="Не могу, потому что все рухнет")*.
2. Вторая часть главная - первая подчиненная: *"Не могу - все рухнет". (="Всё рухнет потому, что не могу".*
3. Обе части "равноправны" (своего рода однородность) "Не могу (,/-) все рухнет".
4. Фраза не распадается на части вообще. "Не могу, все рухнет".

Я не вижу веских оснований исключить ни один из этих подходов. Но при этом двоеточие имеет право на жизнь только в трактовке "вторая часть главная"

[§ 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении | e-reading.club](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/48854/66/Rozental%27_-_Spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyku._Punktuaciya.html)

Ну а тире безусловно возможно в трех оставшихся. Да и в первом (т. е. с основной первой частью) в современных тенденциях вполне допустима по авторским мотивам.

[РАЗДЕЛ 19 Факультативные знаки препинания | orfogrammka.ru](http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827556.html)

Наличие же в первой однородного перечисления на выбор пунктуации здесь, на мой взгляд, не влияет, так что разговоры о каком-то обобщающем слове (даже если бы оно и было) к делу не относятся, это совершенно другой случай: однородных членов внутри предложения, а не бессоюзного сложного.

Я дал ссылку на источник, который мне кажутся более понятным в плане изложения и методологии, в принципе там нет никаких новаций, всё то же самое можно найти и в безусловно авторитетных изданиях.

Answer (score 0):

"Думаю, напрягая мышцы, как я выбиваю стекло. И выныриваю. Пока все там гибнут в автобусе. ... Дальше некуда. Просто свет клином сошелся. **Не сделаю, не выполню, не напрягусь — все рухнет**. Все пропало". [Андрей Битов. Автобус (1962)].

**Итак, по одному предложению трудно судить, какой  нужен знак**, в действительности здесь между предложениями **условные отношения**: если не сделаю, не выполню, не напрягусь, то все рухнет. В этом случае классическим знаком является тире.

Вообще говоря, существует понятие **о причинно-следственных отношениях между предложениями,** то есть одно предложение (первое или второе) может быть причиной, следствием, условием другого предложения. В общем случае такие отношение можно обозначить **тире**.

Двоеточие ставится, если вы хотите **точно обозначить** **направление связи** как  "следствие - причина": Он покраснел: ему было стыдно убить человека безоружного". Это классическое двоеточие, но постановка тире здесь также возможна.

Comment: Вся беда в том, что автор, судя по всему, **сам** ещё не определился с тем, что считать тут выводом, а что причиной или условием. Поэтому (и только поэтому) я за тире. А вот вашего "итак" не понимаю совершенно.

Comment: А какой автор? Перед нами вроде бы текст известного писателя А. Битова, там стоит тире.  А автору нашего вопроса надо объяснить его постановку. Или здесь другая ситуация?

Comment: *А какой автор?* - Павел. К Битову вопросов нет.

Comment: Так у Павла, наверное,   только одно предложение, вот он и мучается с ним. Содержание его не очень ясное, а для постановки двоеточия такая ясность необходима, в то время как тире - это универсальный (почти беспроигрышный) знак.